# Rpp, Rinside support for R packages?

Tags: c++, r, package, rcpp, rinside

Does anyone have decent insight on certain R packages that can work with RInside out of box? I am looking for hopeful support with the R packages of:
quantstrat,
quantmod,
PerformanceAnalytics,
and TTR
In other words, can I call R functions directly within these R packages listed from my C++ if I used RInside. If not, do I have  extra coding or tweaking on the packages or my own R/C++ code to properly implement? 
Big thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do understand that RInside calling R code *still calls R code*, right?

There is no magic speed gain by simply replacing your interactive prompt, or R script, with a call from a C++ program wrapping around it.

For concrete examples, see `examples/standard/rinside_sample2.cpp` and `examples/standard/rinside_sample4.cpp` both of which call the [fPortfolio](http://cran.r-project.org/package=fPortfolio) package (in response to similar questions for examples).  And no, they don't solve the problem faster, but they may give C++ programmers easy access to some R functionality.

The package comes with a large set of examples. Feel free to experiment with those, and maybe time or profile them.  But no silver bullet...

Comment: Ok Dirk, I will look at that. I am not trying to speed up R with C++, I am just trying to expedite my workflow from the coding side. I will take a look at the examples you list. Either way, your contributions to the R community are huge. I am very thankful to developers like to you to make R a really powerful tool! Big thanks!

Comment: Ok -- new RInside release pending by the way, with better support for errors in the submitted R code which won't bring the app down with it.